# Should I file a bug report if the USB audio quits working after a kernel upgrade?

Tags: sound, kernel, updates

I'm fairly new to Linux, I've been using Ubuntu for about two years and this is the first time I've had a serious problem that wasn't self inflicted. A few days ago my computer updated the kernel from 3.13.0-100 to 3.13.0-101, when it did, my USB headphones quit working. Or rather, the CM108 Audio Controller stopped showing up as a sound output option. I still had the built in audio and the HDMI port as options, but not the USB. Then when I tried to shut the computer down, the launcher and the bar across the top went away, as did the shortcuts on my desktop, but then it just hung there showing the desktop background, and I had to power button the computer.

I've booted to 3.13.0-100, and the problems go away. I don't know if this is the kind of problem that should be reported to the official bug tracking or this is a problem that's specific to me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the kernel can cause problems that sometimes are bugs and sometimes are not. For example, updating the kernel in an Ubuntu guest OS running in VirtualBox can cause fullscreen to stop working, but this is not a bug and it is easily fixed. Report the bug and leave it to the subscribers to the bug's notifications to decide whether your problem with USB headphones not working after a kernel upgrade is a confirmed bug. If it is a confirmed bug, reporting it will help it to be fixed in future package updates.

When reporting the bug it might be relevant to provide information about the proprietary graphics driver if you have one installed.